# What does the expression 方便倒是方便 mean?

Tags: expressions

"方便倒是方便" seems like a fixed expression, and from context it seems to be rejecting "is it convenient?" as a reason for doing something. I can't find an actual definition, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

方便倒是方便 roughly means *though it's convenient*. Usually it goes like 方便倒是方便, 可是 ... ... It implies there could be some other negative factors or concerns (though it's convenient).

E.g. (quote from [online](http://www.sohu.com/a/202073148_732743)):

> 方便火锅方便倒是方便, 其安全性又是另外一回事。

Comment: Here's another (perhaps simpler) example from online: 我听说可以在出国前提前拿到国外手机号码,**方便倒是方便,但是**真有这个必要吗?

Answer (score 1):

Without getting too wordy in translation:

你方便帮我取下包裹吗？
Could you pick up my parcel for me?

方便倒是方便，但是我现在还有别的事要做。
Yes, but right now I have something else to do.

方便倒是方便 here = yes